# Partial order on the set of all topologies; minimal and maximal elements on this partial order.

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

The problem statement is as follows

Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the set of all possible topologies on a set $X$. Define the binary relation $\leq$ on $\mathscr{T} \times \mathscr{T}$ by $\tau_{1} \leq \tau_{2} \iff \tau_{1}$ is coarser than $\tau_{2}$. Verify that $\leq$ is a partial ordering of $\mathscr{T}$. Does $\mathscr{T}$ have maximal and minimal elements? If so, what are they?

To show the partial ordering properties was easy. I am stuck on showing the maximal and minimal elements. It seems to me that the minimal element is $\tau_{m} = \{ \emptyset, X \}$ and the maximal element is $\tau_{M} = \mathscr{P}(X) = \{ A : A \subseteq X \}$. The definition for minimal and maximal element is the following

Def. Let $(P, \leq)$ be a partially ordered set and $S \subseteq P$. Then, $m \in S$ is a minimal element of $S$ iff. there is no $s \in S$ such that $s \leq m$ and $m \neq s$. An element $M \in S$ is a maximal element of $S$ iff. there is no $s \in S$ such that $M \leq s$ and $M \neq s$.

Comment: You are right about the maximal and minimal topologies. BTW, they have names of their own.

Comment: @IvanNeretin the discrete and indiscrete topologies are the names. But how do I prove that these are indeed minimal and maximal? That is within which I have difficulties. It seems to me intuitively clear but I am perhaps unable to apply the definition of minimal and maximal element to show it rigorously.

Comment: Well, any topology must contain $\emptyset$ and $X$, otherwise it isn't a topology, hence there can't be a topology coarser than the indiscrete one, can it?

Comment: @IvanNeretin that is true yes and the power set is the largest collection of subsets of a set. But I was thinking that there might be topologies which are not comparable. Also I thought that this argument wasn't rigorous enough.

Comment: Non-comparability is not an issue. A poset can have many minimal elements that are incomparable. (Take all non-empty subsets of a set and the singletons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about the minimal (indiscrete, your $\tau_m$) topology and maximal (discrete, your $\tau_M$) topology.

The proof that they have this property is easy:

Suppose $\tau \le \tau_m$. Then $\tau \subseteq \tau_m$ by definition.
Axiom 1 of a topology says that $\emptyset \in \tau$ and $X \in \tau$ which just says $\tau_m \subseteq \tau$. So two inclusions give us $\tau=\tau_m$.

(I use the reformulation of the definition of a minimal element in a poset $P$: $m$ is minimal iff $\forall p \in P: p \le m \to p=m$. For maximal elements we have a similar reformulation).

So suppose $\tau_M \le \tau$. Then $\tau_M \subseteq \tau$ but $\tau \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X) = \tau_M$ is true by the **definition** of a topology as a family of subsets of $X$ (axiom 0, in a way) and so again $\tau=\tau_M$ is immediate and $\tau_M$ is maximal.

In this poset there are even a minimum and a maximum, a much stronger notion than a maximal or minimal element. The former are unique, the latter need not be.